# AWS CLI returns unauthroized from inside EC2. Same access key works from local VM

Tags: aws-cli

I have two VMs. One is located in our lab, other one is an AWS EC2 instance. I do aws configure and set my Access Key and ID in both of them.

Any aws command works well from my lab VM but not working from inside AWS EC2 instance
Initially I suspected some mis-configuation in keys and profile precedence so ran aws sts get-caller-identity in both the VMs, both return the exact same value so that's not the issue.

I also tried upgrading/downgrading aws cli but both machines but it did not help. Not sure how to move forward.

```
[root@XXX-C13-202 ~]# aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "6766XXXXXXX",
    "UserId": "AIDAIDXXXXXXXX",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::6766XXXXXXX:user/r*****m"
}
[root@XXX-C13-202 ~]# aws ec2 describe-instances
```

This Works!!

```
ubuntu@ip-10-51-23-131:~$ /usr/local/bin/aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AIDAIDXXXXXXXX",
    "Account": "6766XXXXXXX",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::6766XXXXXXX:user/r*****m"
}
ubuntu@ip-10-51-23-131:~$ /usr/local/bin/aws ec2 describe-instances
```

> An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`
> This fails

AWS cli version in EC2 - `aws-cli/2.9.19 Python/3.9.11 Linux/3.13.0-92-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.14 prompt/off`

Tried different versions of AWS cli and verified the credentials are set properly in both the VM

Comment: Would the output of the command offer any hints if ran with --debug flag?

Comment: No, it pretty much says the same thing but as xml response